# libusb_open return LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS in jni android

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, libusb

I want to access a usb device from c++ native code in ROOTed android device (**4.4**)using **libusb1.0.22**. First, I call libusb_init successfully and then call libusb_open but get ***LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS*** error. Why this error is occurring while the device is rooted?

---

Answer (score 0):

**A**

Also on rooted device you MUST permissions! (like linux...)

(1) You MUST to turn off the SELinux (setenforce 0)

(2) You MUST to give file permissions (chmod 666 /dev/bus/usb/*/*), after that your USB connected to the Android device. you can do it with adb over wifi if you have only one USB port. (or to change the device rules to attach USB device node with 666 permissions)

(*) You can use "adb shell run-as" to check your App permissions.

**B**

(1) You need to check that your device is also work in HOST mode.

(2) You need to check if your USB cable is OTG.

Comment: About 'turn off SELinux', only if it's work on your device. "In Android 5.0 and later, SELinux is fully enforced, building on the permissive release of Android 4.3 and the partial enforcement of Android 4.4." https://source.android.com/security/selinux

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Why do we need root privilege to  access USB device from c++ native while we can directly use android.usb.host api? Is it mandatory to have root privilege or there is another solution to solve this.

Comment: You NOT MUST rooted device. you can get USB permissions from Java layer, send the USB fd from Java to libusb c++ code, and work with it.

Comment: Do we use libusb_open in c++ native in android? i use this function in native code for device not rooted, an error is returned

Comment: You see example how to do it with this project: https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera (libuvc works on top of libuvc). good luck.